# jQuery Siblings Selector does not working on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

$(".list").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("select");
  $(this).siblings(".add").toggleClass("exclude");
});
```

```css
.select {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}

.list {
  height: 200px;
}

.exclude {
  background: grey;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="Add New Events"></div>
  <div><button class="add"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Eat</button></div>
  <div><button class="add"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Workout</button></div>
  <div><button class="add"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Sleep</button></div>
  <div><button class="add"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Laundry</button></div>
  <div><button class="add"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Study</button></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do, I want to make each button is able to toggle a classlist to itself and toggle another classlist to other buttons when it is clicked. Therefore, i am trying to use the siblings selector to select other buttons but it does not work. Can someone tell me why and help me to solve it?

Comment: No link please.....

Comment: Post your code as text not a picture. No one wants to transcribe your code to try to debug it.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first time to ask question on stack overflow. I just edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<button>`s are not direct siblings of each other. Each of them is wrapped in a `<div>`. Therefore the code you need is going to be something like

```js
$(this).parent().siblings().children(".add").toggleClass("exclude");
```